# Is anyone else having problems "Favoriting" Question from the Android Browser?

Tags: support, android-browser

Even when I zoom in all the way on the Android.stackexchange.com site, I still can't click on the "Favorite" star.  My tap, no matter how accurate, hits the Downvote or the Facebook icon.  Anyone else have this problem?

Btw, I wan't sure where to post this, meta or not.  Techincally it's a problem I'm having on my Android phone, so appropriate for android.SE but, it's also an issue I'm having with the site so its meta material.  Very tough choice.

**UPDATE:** At Gary's suggestion I addressed this issue at the meta.stackoverflow site as it appears to be affecting all the sites running the "Beta" template.  If you are experiencing this issue or have a solution please refer to the question here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66217/i-cant-add-a-favorite-in-the-stackexchange-beta-site-templates-from-the-androi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, same here on HTC Incredible with default browser. I suggest putting it on SO's meta site since it's probably a problem across all SE sites. It's similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65152/150549), which unfortunately doesn't seem to have many views.

Comment: Good point. Will do next time I'm at the computer.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66217/i-cant-add-a-favorite-in-the-stackexchange-beta-site-templates-from-the-androi

Answer (score 1):

Yes. (Motorola Droid.)

I didn't have a problem on Meta, so I wonder if the Facebook icon isn't overlapping a bit.

Comment: Hmmm, odd, I'm on my moto droid (dolphin browser) and I can't fav in meta.